# CouchDB Failing on OS X

Tags: couchdb, macports, homebrew

I recently installed CouchDB using Homebrew and am running into the following error when I run the "couchdb" command. I'm on OS X 10.7.5:

```
Apache CouchDB 1.2.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I'd previously had couchdb running just fine, but reinstalled recently to try and upgrade. I'm not sure at all how to diagnose this problem.

I've tried setting my file permissions, but they seem to be fine and don't have any effect on this problem.

I've also tried uninstalling from homebrew and reinstalling with `sudo port install couchdb`. Nothing seems to work.

I'm running into this problem on a Macbook Pro and an iMac. Same error, same installation method.

Thanks, All!

Comment: Maybe try this on superuser or serverfault (this doesn't seem like a great fit for stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2):

This link has everything you need.
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX

This line seems of particular interest for you:

```
brew remove --force openssl erlang couchdb icu4c spidermonkey nspr
```

then

```
brew update
brew outdated
brew install erlang
brew install couchdb
```

If all else fails scroll down to install from source.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't say anything about Homebrew problem, but you may try [binary package](http://people.apache.org/~jan/dist/packages/mac/1.2.1/) made by [Jan Lehnardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21269/jan-lehnardt). Currently, it should successfully handle updates from 1.2.0 - follow the mailing list [discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.devel/23787/focus=24341) for more info.

Note, that this package is a little experimental now, but any feedback are welcomed!